# Automatically create hyperlinks with parameters, based on data in another column

Tags: google-sheets, links

(This question was posted [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/script-to-automatically-fill-a-cell-based-on-another-cell-onedit) by [Tasos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/73091/tasos?tab=topactivity), but then deleted). I quote a part of it:

---

At the moment, I have a cell which used to create a hyperlink on the next column. This is what I have done at the moment.

The first cell (in B4 for example) has this format `123456.789` and the hyperlink:

```
=IF(B4="","",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.example.com/?tag1=",LEFT(B4, FIND(".", B4)-1) ,"&tag2=",RIGHT(B4, Len(B4)-FIND(".", B4)) ), B4))
```

The result of the link will be: `http://www.example.com/?tag1=123456&tag2=789`

However, I have to update the column with the hyperlink manually, every time. How can I make it so that every time an entry is added to column B, a hyperlink is created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with [`arrayformula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en):

```
=arrayformula(if(B1:B="",,hyperlink("http://www.example.com/?tag1=" & regexreplace(""&B1:B, "\.", "&tag2="), B1:B)))
```

The main changes are: passing in the entire column B1:B and wrapping the formula in `arrayformula`. This will result in it being automatically applied to every cell in B.  (If you have a header row, replace B1:B by B2:B everywhere.)

But I also made a few improvements to the formula.

- I use `if(B1:B="",,hyperlink(...))` instead of `if(B1:B="","",hyperlink(...))` The first version leaves the cell *blank*, the second puts empty string in it. These are subtly different states of a cell: the difference is invisible but affects the outcome of `isblank` and `query` commands. (When a string is required, i.e., for string comparison, blank cells are coerced to empty strings; this is why  `B1:B=""` matches both blank cells and those with empty string.)
- Instead of a bunch of `find`, `left`, `right`, `len`, I used substitution: `regexreplace(""&B1:B, "\.", "&tag2=")` replaces dot with "&tag2=". (This assumes that you have only one dot in the input, otherwise the input is ambiguous.)  An interesting detail: the concatenation `""&B1:B` is needed to coerce the input to string form; otherwise `regexreplace` chokes up on numeric input such as 1234.567
- In almost all cases, concatenation is easier expressed with & operator than with `concatenate` command. Less typing, fewer parentheses to mess up.